# Permutation test in R multiple p values

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, permutation-test

I've got this data:

```
             V1          V2
1  0.0000000000 0.000841582
2  0.0000000000 0.000841582
3  0.0007987220 0.000841582
4  0.0000000000 0.000841582
5  0.0000000000 0.000841582
6  0.0000000000 0.000841582
7  0.0000000000 0.000841582
8  0.0006561680 0.000841582
9  0.0000000000 0.000841582
10 0.0000000000 0.000841582
11 0.0004514673 0.000841582
12 0.0009487666 0.000841582
13 0.0001770225 0.000841582
14 0.0007212405 0.000841582
15 0.0004296455 0.000841582
16 0.0000000000 0.000841582
17 0.0019710907 0.000841582
18 0.0006717421 0.000841582
19 0.0007855460 0.000841582
20 0.0004738214 0.000841582
21 0.0011086475 0.000841582
22 0.0017499205 0.000841582
23 0.0018606574 0.000841582
24 0.0015873016 0.000841582
25 0.0010107817 0.000841582
26 0.0020727341 0.000841582
27 0.0017543860 0.000841582
28 0.0043346337 0.000841582
```

What I'm trying to do is a permutation test. I'd like to calculate a p-value for each observation using the difference between each v1 and v2. v2 is some average relevant to the data so it should all be the same for each observation. I'm using the `coin` package:

`independence_test(test$V1 ~ test$V2, data=test)` and I'm not getting what I want:

```
Z = Inf, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

I've also tried;

```
independence_test(test$V2 ~ test$V3 | as.factor(test$V1), data=test)
```

where `V1` is a vector of letters corresponding to each observation. The above code gives me an error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to take V1-V2, but could you please elaborate on what it is that you want to test?

Comment: @Dave I'd like to see if a V1 observation is significantly bigger / smaller then V2. meaning, is the difference likely not happening by chance. Each v1 observation is a binomial variable, if that matters. Writing this comment I understand perhaps the test isn't the best - I have to take proportions into consideration. Is there an R version of the proportion permutation test?

Comment: It sounds like you have 28 distinct one-sample proportion tests to do. I don’t see how permutations come up.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the insight. When I read about the specific test I want permutations seemed to match as it dealt with different proportions, but the z-test does seem more fitting.

Comment: Which z-test? That can have a couple of meanings.

Comment: @Dave http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/one-proportion-z-test-in-r This is the one I had in mind. I'm using the original data used to calculate V1 - the number of successes divided by the num of attempts. Some of my P values are funky - literally the number 1. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: You may be seeing issues related to having zero successes, but that warrants a separate question.

Comment: @Dave That is indeed the case. So I wonder - say we have 50 attempts compared to 5000, both with 0 successes. Are they treated the same? It is far more likely that the 50 attempts 0 successes is happening by chance. How do I treat them differently? Your help is very much appreciated, by the way.

Comment: Cross Validated (and probably the other Stacks, too) works best when separate questions are posted separately, not when one question leads to another in comments or a chat.

Comment: What do you mean with "I'd like to calculate a p-value for each observation"?

Comment: @ping There are 28 distinct proportion tests.

Comment: Ok, so I guess the question should be fixed because it's not clear what's the OP is asking. Also, there's no indication of the size of the sample from where the proportions were estimated.

Comment: @ping I agree, it was my mis-understanding. I've flagged my question so it will be closed.